# Javascript - Moving occurrences of undefined to the end of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking to move all occurrences of `undefined` to the end of an array.

So for example if my array looks like: `[undefined,"bbc", "cnn"]` the function will create: `["bbc", "cnn", undefined]`

I have built a script that can do that:

```
arr = [undefined,"bbc", "cnn"]

var loopNo = 0
for (var f = 0; f < arr.length; f++) {
  loopNo += 1
  var keyNo = loopNo - 1
  if (arr[f] === undefined){ 
     arr.push(arr.splice(keyNo, 1)[0]);
  }
}

console.log(arr)
```

However if `undefined` occurs more than once it doesn't move it - i.e `[undefined , undefined, "cnn"]`

How do I make it so `undefined` is shifted to the end of the array every-time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you:

1. only want to move `undefined` to the end of an array without affecting others,
2. are okay with creating intermediate arrays,

here's a simple way to accomplish this, using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let arr = [undefined, undefined,"bbc", "cnn", "abc"];

const arrDefined = arr.filter(el => el !== undefined);
const arrUndefined = arr.filter(el => el === undefined);
arr = [...arrDefined, ...arrUndefined];

console.log('arr:', arr);
// [ "bbc", "cnn", "abc", undefined, undefined ]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Better way [Big O(N)]:**

```js
const shiftUndefined = (arr) => {
  let duplicate = [];
  for (let i = 0, len = arr.length, j = len - 1, k = 0; k <= j; i++) {
    const item = arr[i];
    if (item === undefined) {
      duplicate[j--] = undefined;
    } else {
      duplicate[k++] = item;
    }
  }
  return duplicate;
};
const arr = [undefined, "bbc", "cnn"];
const arr2 = [undefined, undefined, "cnn"];
console.log(shiftUndefined(arr)); // [ 'bbc', 'cnn', undefined ]
console.log(shiftUndefined(arr2)); // [ 'cnn', undefined, undefined ]
```

**Keep Same ref: Big O(N)**

```js
function sameRefMove(array) {
  const filtered = array.filter(Boolean);
  let index = 0;
  while (index < filtered.length) {
    array[index] = filtered[index++];
  }
  while (index < array.length) {
    array[index++] = undefined;
  }
  return array;
}
var array = [undefined, "bbc", "cnn"];
console.log(sameRefMove(array));
console.log(sameRefMove([undefined, undefined, "cnn"]));
```

**Using reduce:**

```
const move = (arr) => {
  const [filtered, noValue] = arr.reduce(
    ([filtered, noValue], item) => {
      if (item === undefined) noValue.push(undefined);
      else filtered.push(item);
      return [filtered, noValue];
    },
    [[], []]
  );
  return filtered.concat(noValue);
};
let arr = [undefined, "bbc", "cnn"];
arr = move(arr);
console.log(arr);
arr = [undefined, undefined, "cnn"];
arr = move(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

**Just use sort if performance is not concern.**

```js
const arr = [undefined,"bbc", "cnn"]
console.log(arr.sort()) // [ 'bbc', 'cnn', undefined ]
```

Comment: it looks like that op wants to keep the same object reference ...

Comment: added sample to keep the same ref. However, I don't see any point in keeping the same ref here.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate from the end and splice and push `undefined` values.

```js
function move(value, array) {
    var i = array.length - 1;
    while (i--) {
        if (array[i] === value) {
            array.push(array.splice(i, 1)[0]);
        }
    }
    return array;
}

var array = [undefined, "bbc", "cnn"];

console.log(move(undefined, array));
```